# Propagate MouseClick event from Papplet to object class

Tags: java, eclipse, processing

So, I am using eclipse and processing to do some of the heavier coding in Java, but I am having a little trouble with my derived classes--

I have a histogram class with a member variable parent which is the main PApplet running the program. Processing already has a nice MouseClicked event and I want my histogram class to be able to have its own onclicked method.

So here is the big question: how do I get that MouseClicked event to trickle down to my objects?

```
public RunOverview(PApplet p, float[] simBuckets, float[] pointBuckets, int xP, int yP, int len, int hi)
{
    this.parent = p;
    this.xPos = xP;
    this.yPos = yP;
    this.height = hi; 
 }
// SOMEHOW LISTEN FOR parent.MouseClicked()........
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now your `RunOverview` class stores an reference to the `PApplet`. You could also do the reverse and have the `PApplet` store a reference to the `RunOverview` instance! In your constructor, you could call some function like `registerOverview(this)` that is defined in your processing code to save the reference in the `PApplet`. Then, when the mouse functions are called, you can directly call the `RunOverview`'s functions from there!

```
public RunOverview(PApplet p, float[] simBuckets, float[] pointBuckets, int xP, int yP, int len, int hi)
{
    this.parent = p;
    this.xPos = xP;
    this.yPos = yP;
    this.height = hi; 
    p.registerOverview(this);
 }
 public void mousePressed(int x, int y){}
 public void mouseReleased(int x, int y){}
```

And then

```
RunOverview thingy;
void setup(){}
void draw(){}
void registerOverview(RunOverview view){
  thingy = view;
}
void mousePressed(){
  thingy.mousePressed(mouseX,mouseY);
}
void mouseReleased(){
  thingy.mouseReleased(mouseX,mouseY);
}
```

Just make sure to register it before you do anything else, or else you'll get some Null Pointer Exceptions.